# Возможно ли создание нескольких таблиц одним запросом

Tags: php, mysql

Есть скрипт

```
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','root');
define('DB_NAME','test');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if ($link) {
  mysql_query('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS '.DB_NAME, $link);
} else {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Make my_db the current database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if ($db_selected) {
  // If we couldn't, then it either doesn't exist, or we can't see it.
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
          `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `nickname` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
          `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
          `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";

  $sql2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
          `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `category_name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
          `description` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";

$result = $sql.$sql2;

    if(mysql_query($result, $link)){
        echo "SUCCESS!";
      }
    }


mysql_close($link);
```

Одна таблица создается а 2 к сожалению не выходит

Comment: точку с запятой не пробовали ставить между запросами на создание? у вас в конце второго есть `;` а  в конце первого нет, по идее увас там вообще строка слитно написана в тоге `CHARSET=utf8CREATE`

Comment: пробовал конкатенировать с пробелом и ; не выходит

Comment: Не пользуйтесь deprecated API, переходите на `mysqli`/`pdo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос использование mysqli, функция mysqli_multi_query может отправить запрос с созданием неогранниченного колличества таблиц.

Answer (score 0):

Одним запросом - невозможно. Одной командой (например, содержащей несколько запросов, если коннектор позволяет, или вызывающей выполнение процедуры) - можно.

Касательно кода в вопросе - согласно [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php)

> mysql_query() посылает **один** запрос (посылка нескольких запросов не поддерживается) активной базе данных сервера

Comment: [не все с вами согласны](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980803/executing-multiple-sql-queries-in-one-statement-with-php/13982705#13982705)

Comment: ремарка про один запрос, кстати, возможно относится только к запросам возвращающих набор данных. Ведь в целом нет проблемы отправить серверу команду на выполнение нескольких запросов разом. Проблема может быть в том, чтобы вернуть клиенту несколько датасетов.

Comment: @teran Эммм... пардон, в чём не все со мной согласны? Да, использование multi-statement для соединения описано в http://php.net/manual/ru/mysql.constants.php#mysql.client-flags - но я и говорил, что коннектор должен позволять.

Comment: я к тому. что было бы неплохо расширить ответ, указав, что при должных настройках соединения `mysql_query` может выполнить  несколько запросов одним вызовом. Я с первого прочтения не совсем понял ваш ответ. Что имелось в виду под разными коннекторами, это `mysql`, `mysqli`, `PDO` или просто настройки `mysql`. При прочтении складывается впечатление (особенно со ссылкой на документацию), что выполнить несколько инструкций одним вызовом невозможно.

Comment: т.е. все таки можно создать 2 таблицы, нужно просто использовать multi-statement http://php.net/manual/ru/mysql.constants.php#mysql.client-flags?

Comment: @v.krasnov ну теоретически - да. Хотя я бы настоятельно не рекомендовал так делать... просто Вы частично теряете контроль за процессом. Допустим, одна таблица не создалась. Как Вы узнаете о проблеме? Как Вы узнаете, какая именно и по какой причине? если делать по одной, всё это будет в разы проще.